# What should be my POST URL format be

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I'm new to APIs and i am going through the trailhead to obtain tokens/ add a contact to my subscriber list...

I'm using Postman and trying to add a URL

Should i select POST from drop down and the following URL (edited):
https://MY.marketingcloudapis.com

Then add this to my raw body of text:

```
POST /contacts/v1/contacts
```

or should i just put in 
https://MY.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts

All documentation seems suggests i should be typing POST /contacts/v1/contacts after my URL but i can't find an API tool that supports that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the base URLs from your API configuration page. It will be mcXXXXX.YYYY.marketingcloudapis.com where XXXXX is your org specific value and YYYY is auth/soap/rest based on what action you are going to perform.

Since you are new, I would suggest you use Postman Marketing Cloud collection to interact with the APIs first. This has a bunch of very useful request templates. Most importantly, it has the Contact POST request as well.

Here is the link to download the collection:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman

Comment: awesome, thanks very much - appreciate that you appreciate a newbie :)